# How to target last row in a list with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am listing the friends of user in his/her profile as a picture (like facebook) and for the specified width, I can only list 9 picture with 'margin-right: 5px, margin-bottom: 5px'. For every 9th element I needed to remove margin-right and I did that with:

```
:nth-child(9n){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

So the row fits perfect to specified width. The problem is I also need to make it fit height. So, to remove the margin-bottom, I tried this. But this doesn't work:

```
:nth-last-of-type(-n+9){
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Because in friends listing user may not have 9 18 27 user in the list. If user has 13 friends, this css above will remove last 9, but I don't want it to touch the row above. Only last row. So, how many ever friends user have, I gotta remove margin-bottom of last row.

I hope I explained clearly. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to remove the bottom of? every 9th element as well?

Comment: Basically I am trying to remove bottom of last row. 
This is an example to what I am doing.
http://www.techlicious.com/images/computers/facebook-featured-friends-451px.jpg

Comment: I am trying to post html but when I paste html, in preview this appears "> " > cannot paste the code :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this - with a combination of `:nth-child()` and general sibling `~` selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/twu14gu0/

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
li:nth-child(9n) {
    color: red;
}
li:nth-child(9n+1):nth-last-child(-n+9),
li:nth-child(9n+1):nth-last-child(-n+9) ~ li {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li><li>*</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

**Extra knowledge**

There is way to access first and last elements in any kind of things(Ex: li, td, div..)

1. To access first you can use `:first-child{}`. (ex: `li:first-child`)
2. To access first you can use `:last-child{}`. (ex: `li:last-child`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the last-child pseudo class to get the last element.

```
:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: I need to remove bottom of last row not last element..! The div can hold up to 9 element in the row. I imagine 9 squares next to each other. So, in my last row I may have up to 9 squares. So if I list 10 squares, the last row will have 1 square. if I list 15, the last row will have 6 because a row (width) can hold up to 9 squares.

Comment: You should probably post your HTML in the question so it's a bit clearer.